# egit on Windows not working right: error "In order to use a remote for push, you must specify at least one URI and at least one Ref Mapping"

Tags: git, egit

On my Ubuntu system both egit and git from the command line work perfectly on a remote repo.  But I cannot make egit on my Windows system successfully access that same repo.  I've tried everything from copying the exact same config file, to inspecting the egit config windows and duplicating them.  At one point my Windows system egit could push but could not pull.  More recently it does neither.

Most recently the error message is "In order to use a remote for push, you must specify at least one URI and at least one Ref Mapping".  Below is my config file (but with a valid IP) that works fine on my Ubuntu system but not on egit on my Windows system.

Does anyone know why I can't just use the exact same config file for Linux and Windows and/or what that error means and how to solve it?

[core]

```
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
```

[remote "origin"]

```
url = ssh://username@000.00.00.000/source/my_repo.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

[branch "master"]

```
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Do you have any more specific error messages coming from EGit?  Do the same commands work with "vanilla" Git (however you're accustomed to using it on Windows or Msysgit)?

Comment: We fixed this by just re-cloning the entire remote repo via Egit's menus.  Once Egit, itself, cloned it then egit was able to push and pull from it.